# Loop through numerous variables

Tags: java, android

I have 48 variables (TextViews), like tv1, tv2, tv3, tv4...tv48.

I want to set a value for these variables, with a for loop, since I do not want to write down the same row 48 times.

Something like this:

```
for (int i=1; i<49; i++)
{
        "tv"+i.setText(i);
}
```

How to achieve this?

Comment: Why don't you put all these variables in an array and cycle through them?

Comment: Or a [`List`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/List.html)...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Initialize them like this:

```
TextView[] tv = new TextView[48];
```

Then you can set text in them using `for` loop like this:

```
for(int i=0; i<48; i++)
{
   tv[i].setText("your text");
}
```

EDIT: In your XML file, give identical IDs to all the textviews. For e.g. tv0, tv1, tv2 etc.
Initialize a string array, which will have these IDs as string.

```
String ids[] = new String[48];
for(int i=0; i<48; i++)
{
   ids[i] = "tv" + Integer.toString(i);
}
```

Now, to initialize the array of `TextView`, do this:

```
for(int i=0; i<48; i++)
{
   int resID = getResources().getIdentifier(ids[i], "id", "your.package.name");
   tv[i] = (TextView) findViewById(resID);
}
```

Comment: And how should I declare  tv1 = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.tv1); ?

Comment: Very nice! Thank you! Use getResources() instead of resources.

Answer (score 2):

```
TextView[] textViews = new TextView[48];

int[] ids = new int[48];

for(int i=0;i<48;i++) {
    textViews[i] = (TextView) findViewById(ids[i]);
}

for(int i=0;i<48;i++) {
    textViews[i].setText(String.valueOf(i));
}
```

Here, you will need to add all the IDs to the `ids` array.

Comment: @Jug6ernaut Thanks for the edit, but I put it in separate loops as more often than not, people need the assignment and setText() functionality in different places.

Comment: You need to first get Resource IDs of all the `TextView`s before you use `ids` array.

Comment: `Here, you will need to add all the IDs to the ids array.`

Answer (score 1):

```
"tv"+i
```

can be used only with Reflection.

I would put those TextViews in an array and

```
for (int i=0; i<textViews.length; i++)
{
        textViews[i].setText(""+i);//be a String. not an int...
}
```

I would use, where `textViews = new TextViews[]{tv1,tv2..tv48}`

I hope it helps!

Comment: setText() takes a String, not an int as a parameter.

Comment: very true, and I hope he understand the idea and can set a whaetver text there